# Customizing material UI Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize the paper component to have a width of the full viewport. To be very frank I have a lot such problems if I try to customize any small details.

What I want to be able to do is customize the css that is being shown in the inspect element. In this particular case customize MuiBox-root-138 to have a padding of 0.

[image: Inspect element of the frontend from which I would like to remove padding]

```
const styles = theme =>({

root:{
    padding: 0,
    width:"100%"
     }
});
```

This doesn't work

What would be the elegant way of manipulating inner components of a MUI component.
Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code you are using to render this (not just the styles).

Comment: I think you can put it inside div with 100% width

Comment: does your paper have a className?

Comment: same problem but I just have all of the required things.
point is that all of my styles work else of width, even with:
width:"100% !important"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried different ways and this worked:

```
    minWidth:"100% !important",
    maxWidth:"100% !important",
```

I'm not sure if it's the same for you but it works.